# finding median element in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I also want to find the median age field for my documents, and found an example online using percentile functionality.

```
curl localhost:9200/residents/_search  -d '{"size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
     "percentile" : {
         "percentile" : {
             "field" : "age" ,
             "percents" : [50]}}}}'
```

but I receive error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "unknown_named_object_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [percentile]",
        "line" : 6,
        "col" : 25
      }
    ],
    "type" : "unknown_named_object_exception",
    "reason" : "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [percentile]",
    "line" : 6,
    "col" : 25
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only percentiles aggregation in ElasticSearch.Try using

```
curl localhost:9200/residents/_search  -d '{"size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
     "percentile" : {
         "percentiles" : {
             "field" : "age" ,
             "percents" : [50]}}}}'
```